# How to set the google custom search to dispaly the results of search on a paticular page like search.php?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have implemented google custom search engine on my website http://www.finalyearondesk.com/

What I want is that when user enters his query into my own defined search bar, then the results [By result I mean the result that is displayed right after just entering the query  and hitting enter, for example "ubuntu"] must be displayed in this page... http://www.finalyearondesk.com/search.php . At now the result are just displayed where I have inserted the code that google has given me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google custom search is a JavaScript Ajax widget. The browser talks to Google independent of your site.

If you want results in your search.php page, either put the search-box on the search.php page, or query Google server side, then display the formatted results any way you like. This is very not ideal because Google limits the number of queries you can do.

Long story short, you have to live with the ads and limited placement options google gives you.

You can always attempt to write your own web search engine if you don't like it [/sarcasm]